# Minitest - testing helper method that uses request params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am porting an application that used RSpec successfully to test helper methods over to MiniTest. The following is the method in application_helper.rb

```
def active_controller?(controller_name)
  params[:controller] == controller_name ? 'active' : nil
end
```

It is something that is used in views to help with active controller highlighting in controllers.

Below is the (not working) test for the helper.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

test 'active_controller? returns correct value' do
    @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    @request.params[:controller] = 'dashboard'
    assert active_controller?('dashboard')
  end
end
```

The problem is that I cant figure out how to access (or stub out) the request params to contain a controller to be able to assert the method returns true.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the pry gem to see what `@request`, `@request.params[:controller]`, and `params[:controller]` actually return.
The assertion `active_controller?('dashboard')` is checking 'dashboard' against `params[:controller]`, which is currently nil, as you've only assigned `@request.params[:controller]` in your test.
If the test is:

```
test 'active_controller? returns correct value' do
  params[:controller] = 'dashboard'
  assert active_controller?('dashboard')
end
```

the assertion is comparing 'dashboard' to `params[:controller]`, which has been assigned.